# Retrieve cell value from a sorted range when an "input" cell value is >= than the first cell in the range AND < than the next cell in the range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write a formula that retrieves a value from a sorted range when another cell value (the "input") is >= than the first cell in the range and < than the next value in this range (if there is a way to do it without sorting the range I'm happy with it too).

I tried using query but I can't find a way to make it work.

This is the sheet I have:

| A (input) | B |
| --- | --- |
| 910 | 0 |
|  | 1000 |
|  | 4000 |
|  | 7000 |

and I would like to retrieve 0.

In this other case I would like to retrieve 4000:

| A (input) | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5440 | 0 |
|  | 1000 |
|  | 4000 |
|  | 7000 |

I need this formula for a `VLOOKUP` search_key that I will use to retrieve another value from cell C  `=VLOOKUP(A2,B2:C5,2,FALSE)`, so instead of having to put the exact value I'm trying to vlookup in `A2` I can get it by comparing `A2` to the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=vlookup(A7,$A$1:$A$4,1,1)
```

or

```
=xlookup(A7,$A$1:$A$4,$A$1:$A$4,,-1)
```

Result:

[image]

Also you can sort directly in formula:

```
=vlookup(A7,sort($A$1:$A$4,1,1),1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know I could do this with a vlookup, thought it was just for exact matches, i was over complicating myself, thank you so much!

Comment: You might also want to take a look at xlookup and all its options for future tasks :)